# BigQuery - add conditions within partitioned sum function

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm want to calculate an expected stock in the future for each day, but I'm stuck in the part where I want to avoid that the expected quantity gets below zero and then adds the newly received quantity. I want that when the quantity gets below 0 it gives me 0 and calculates from that point and not -XXX + new added quantity.

In short, I use the following data points for the calculation:

1. Datestamp
2. Productcode
3. Stock today (qty on day 0)
4. Stockmutation (What I expect to sell & expect to receive as replenishment)

SELECT

Productcode

,    date

,

```
 SUM(stockToday + stockmutation)
       OVER (
           PARTITION BY globalid
               ORDER BY  date) 
                      AS StockFC
```

[Current output with code as above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgIo.png)

I've several types of CASE WHEN, but unfortunately without the wished result. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will summarize only non-negative values and return nulls for negative rows.

```
SELECT
Productcode,
date,
SUM(stockToday + stockmutation)
       OVER (
           PARTITION BY globalid
               ORDER BY  date, stockToday + stockmutation >= 0) 
                      AS StockFC
```

or this. It will summarize values from all rows but replace negative values with 0.

```
SELECT
Productcode,
date,
SUM(IF(stockToday + stockmutation) >= 0, stockToday + stockmutation, 0)
       OVER (
           PARTITION BY globalid
               ORDER BY  date) 
                      AS StockFC
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution with "ORDER BY  date, stockToday + stock mutation >= 0" worked out for me! Just one question still. At the row where I have a positive mutation from a zero stock point, it sums up all the stock mutations from the rows above and substracts that from the newly added stock. Do you know how to fix this?